# Output table linear regression

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am unsure of how you would get the missing values denoted "***" in the table using only the values listed in the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[Output table of linear regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaJcn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The $t-$value for the estimated coefficient $b_i$ is $t_{b_i}=\frac{b_i}{\text{SE}}$,

where $\text{SE}$ is the standard error of coefficient $b_i$. The equation can be transposed for $b_i$ and $\text{SE}$.

[Here](https://misy262.wordpress.com/2019/02/01/overfitting-variable-selection/) is a table where you can check some numbers:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. that has helped a lot, another part is to determine which distribution was used to find the corresponding p-values, how would I find that?

Comment: Can´t you ask that question as a new question? It is more or less just copy and paste.

Comment: Its work in preparation for an exam and the lecturer is uninterested in having people in his office, no solutions are published and I was hoping if I understand one of them more or less, I could apply it to the other years questions but that other part seemed a smaller question and I didnt know if you could offer me a hint

Comment: From the data I´m not sure how the value are calculated. As I said. Just make a copy and paste of your question and post a new question (not much effort). You´ll receive an appropriate answer soon.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help, have a nice day.

Comment: @user3486373 You´re welcome. Good luck with your new question.